# How to get data other than OHLC on quantmod package?

Tags: r, quantmod

When using `getSymbols()` function in R. By default, only OHLC plus Vo, and Ad are given. Is there any way to get other informations such as total shares or turnover rate from `quantmod` or other packages in R?

Comment: If you're not more specific, I'm afraid this is likely to be closed as either "too broad" or "recommend to find a book, tool, library, etc".

Comment: Sorry, I will elaborate my question into more detail. I want to get turnover rate of Apple stock with quantmod. So I use getSymbols("AAPL", from= Sys.Date()-2*365 , to = Sys.Date()) to query stock data in past two years from yahoo. But by default, it returns an xts object with 6 columns, which are AAPL.Open AAPL.High AAPL.Low AAPL.Close AAPL.Volume and AAPL.Adjusted. I am wondering whether there is a way to get turnover rate in the same time?